# SharePoint 2019 - Navigation in Communication sites (Audience targeting?)

Tags: sharepoint-server, audience-targeting, communication-site, 2019

I would like to know if the "audience" is available in the navigation menu for the communication sites in SharePoint 2019. I have been using office 365 and I cannot find the way to hide some parts of the navigation menu for specific people in the communication sites. I am aware that I cannot activate the publishing feature in the communication site, so I am not sure how I can get this functionality?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft is working on Audience Targetting.  Should be available in the first half of 2019.  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Build-your-modern-intranet-with-SharePoint-in-Office-365/bc-p/320834#M3203

Comment: actually they are not working on Audiences for navigation. Just for news.